# force section and subsection to capital letters

Tags: macros, sectioning, capitalization

hi Im trying to renew the section cmd to make all sections in capitals.

i have tried stuff like

```
\newcommand{\tmpsection}[1]{}
\let\tmpsection=\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\tmpsection{\uppercase{#1}}}
```

but no luck.
can anyone help ? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way to achieve the result is by using the `sectsty` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{sectsty,textcase}
\allsectionsfont{\MakeTextUppercase}

\begin{document}
\section{Here's à la page}
\subsection{Straße}
\end{document}
```

I used also `textcase` for `\MakeTextUppercase` is usually more robust than `\MakeUppercase` (and `\uppercase` wouldn't work with accented letters).

This doesn't touch the entries in the table of contents; to get also that some more work should be done.